What is the person who collects money after a performance is called?
In any performance, whether it be a street performance, circus, cabaret etc., what do you call the person who goes around collecting money or tips from the audience? Do different type of performances have different terms for this? If yes, is there a dedicated umbrella term for these? If there isn't, What can be used as an umbrella term for these?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_performance#Collecting_money

@StuartF Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

@StuartF How can I mark the question as answered?

You can't unless someone posts a formal answer.

There's an answer now. You can click the green tick next to it to accept it.

It is sometimes called a bottler, especially in Punch And Judy performances.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_and_Judy

The show is performed by a single puppeteer inside the booth, known since Victorian times as a "professor" or "punchman", and assisted sometimes by a "bottler" who corrals the audience outside the booth, introduces the performance, and collects the money ("the bottle").

https://www.vam.ac.uk/articles/thats-the-way-to-do-it-a-history-of-punch-and-judy

Punch and Judy shows were familiar sights on the streets throughout the 19th century. Their performances were often heralded by drums or panpipes played by the Punchman's accomplice or 'bottler', whose job was to collect the money from the audience.

